# Checking PE header integrity

Tags: neural-network, portable-executable

I have created a project on identifying malicious files using an artificial neural network. I am giving some selected features from PE structure as inputs to the neural network, and it is classifying files correctly. But referring to this answer : "https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37921/windows-pe-file-and-malwares";it said that code can be injected into PE and values in optional header can be changed! I wanted to know if there is any way to know if PE structure has been modified?
One more link about injecting code into PE file: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12532/Inject-your-code-to-a-Portable-Executable-file

Comment: Where have you heard this, and what do you mean by 'modified'? *What* is modified? Values? Structure? It's impossible to answer the question when the question is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting an edit. I have edited the question if its still unclear then let me know! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't know if the pe was modified if you don't have the orignal binary but each compiler or packer have a signature (you can look with rdg for example http://www.rdgsoft.net/) you can use it to see if this signature is not here anymore but it possible that the signature is here even if the binary was modified.

Else you can look if the binary have strange section or if some value in the structure is not logical

you can see also if each section have right protection .text -> execute etc.

if you want to learn more about it you look this link

https://github.com/katjahahn/PortEx/tree/master/masterthesis

You can read the difference strategy (appending to the orignal binary or prependeing or divided in multi part) of a malware and how to detect it.

for instance
[image]

Which functions you should found in the import table `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` etc.

and his tools to test these methods in practice:

https://github.com/katjahahn/PortEx